# Clone object with django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model which can be described as:

Element:
- element has one to one field with ElementData

ElementData: 
- it has ForeignKey to ElementImage - which describes default image

ElementImage:
- it has ForeignKey to ElementData

ElementVideo:
- it has foreignKey to ElementData

Now I want element and all subtables cloned. I tried to use snippet which I found [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/904/). I put this function to Element and ElementData and when I in element try to clone ElementData I have constraint violation. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution:

```
def clone(self):
        old = self
        images = old.element_data.images.all()
        videos = old.element_data.videos.all()
        element_data = self.element_data
        element_data.id = None
        element_data.save()
        for image in images:
            image.id = None
            image.element_data = element_data
            image.save()
        for video in videos:
            video.id = None
            video.element_data = element_data
            video.save()

        new_kwargs = dict([(fld.name, getattr(old, fld.name)) for fld in old._meta.fields if fld.name != 'id']);
        new_kwargs['element_data'] = element_data
        return self.__class__.objects.create(**new_kwargs)
```

Please write what you think about it

Answer (score 3):

Because Element has OneToOne relation to ElementData, you need to clone the ElementData before cloning Element. Like this:

```
class Element(...):
    def clone(self):
        new_kwargs = dict([(fld.name, getattr(old, fld.name)) for fld in old._meta.fields if fld.name != 'id']);
        new_data = self.data.clone()
        new_kwargs['data'] = new_data
        return self.__class__.objects.create(**new_kwargs)
```

Comment: When I do like you said I receive constraint violation when cloning ElementData, I don`t know why...

Comment: if there are no OneToOne relations in ElementData there should not be such problems. Might be helpful if you would show comlete definition of the ElementData model.